# rs232 TE550 PC com port

Tags: usb, rs232

Есть устройство TE550, необходимо отправлять/считывать данные по Com(rs232) порту.
Использую кабель Конвертер USB на COM-порт (9 pin DB9, RS232)
Открываю порт через CoolTerm (9600 8 bits of data, 1 bit of stop, and no
parity.)
Вот такую команду необходимо отправить: `020115003011EE`
а именно

```
Command 50: status request
The status request command is used to request the register response package, without later actions that
may alter the status of the system.
STX = Start byte of the frame (0x02)
ADDR = TE550 logical address [2 bytes]
CMOD = CMOD to refer [1 byte]
TKN1/0 = Frame identification bytes [2 bytes]
TYPE = Selection byte for customizable box (RiqA/B)* [1 byte]
CHKH/L = Checksum [2 bytes]
END = End byte of the frame (0x0D)
Example:
status request from PC to TE550 (address 01), CMOD 1, Token 01, Type 1
[0x02]0115003011EE[0x0D]
```

А в ответ тишина ....

```
TX frames are structured as described before, RX frames are different: they preserve the acknowledgebyte (0x06), the ASCII checksum and the end-byte (0x0D), other information are binary coded (not in
ASCII). Both frames present an identification byte (token).
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Что и как вы отправляете тоже не ясно.

Comment: вопрос в том, правильную ли я команду отправляю исходя из мануала [0x02]0115003011EE[0x0D] .... т.е. нужно отправить 020115003011EE0D или сначала 02 потом 0115003011EE потом 0D

Comment: Разбирайтесь по документации какие байты нужно отправлять, потом смотрите что именно у вас отправляется и сравнивайте с тем, что должно быть.

Comment: Похоже всё дано в шестнадцатеричном виде. В coolterm посылается `020115003011EE0D` через send string в hex-режиме. Но похоже тут какая-то ошибка. По описанию должно быть 10 байт, а в строке `020115003011EE0D` всего 8.

Answer (score 2):

Автор вопроса очевидно *угадал все буквы, но не смог прочитать слово*.

```
Example:
status request from PC to TE550 (address 01), CMOD 1, Token 01, Type 1
[0x02]0115003011EE[0x0D]
```

Правильная *расшифровка* этого примера из документации:

Все данные кроме `STX(0x02)` и `END(0x0D)` передаются в `ASCII` формате.
Строка `0115003011EE` состоит из:

- `"01"` ADDR
- `"1"` CMOD
- `"5003"` код комманды *status request*
- `"01"` TOKEN
- `"1"` TYPE
- `"EE"` CHECKSUM

Таким образом длина комманды в байтах будет 14 и соответственно *Send String* для *CoolTerm* в шестнадцетиричном формате будет:

```
02 30 31 31 35 30 30 33 30 31 31 45 45 0d
```